# How to inject MonoBehaviour class to non Monobehaviour in Unity3d with zenject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dependency-injection, zenject

I want to organize my code as well as I can, but I have some trouble with its organization. I try to use SOLID principles and make separate entities. I want to use MVVM to view ([unity-weld as well](https://github.com/Real-Serious-Games/Unity-Weld)), and DI container ([zenject as well](https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject)).

It's my first project and I'm trying to organize code.

My question is how to inject `LoginViewModel` into `LoginController` as static class using zenject container from `GameInstaller` class.

```
[Binding]
public class LoginViewModel : MonoBehaviour, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _username = "";
    private string _passsword = "";
    private string _errorMessage = "";
    private bool _autologin = false;

    [Inject]
    private LoginController _loginController;

    [Binding]
    public string Username {
        get
        {
            return _username;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_username == value)
            {
                return; // No change.
            }

            _username = value;
            Debug.Log($"SET username: {value}");
            OnPropertyChanged("Username");
        }
    }

    [Binding]
    public string Password {
        get
        {
            return _passsword;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_passsword == value)
            {
                return; // No change.
            }

            _passsword = value;
            Debug.Log($"SET password: {value}");
            OnPropertyChanged("Password");
        }
    }

    [Binding]
    public bool Autologin {
        get
        {
            return _autologin;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_autologin == value)
            {
                return; // No change.
            }

            _autologin = value;
            Debug.Log($"SET autologin: {value}");
            OnPropertyChanged("Autologin");
        }
    }

    [Binding]
    public void LoginButtonClick()
    {
        Debug.Log("LoginButtonClick");

        _loginController.Login(this);
        //ErrorMessage = "blabla";
    }

    [Binding]
    public string ErrorMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return _errorMessage;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_errorMessage == value)
            {
                return; // No change.
            }

            _errorMessage = value;
            Debug.Log($"SET errorMessage: {value}");
            OnPropertyChanged("ErrorMessage");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event to raise when a property's value has changed.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class LoginController
{
    private readonly ApiController _apiController;

    [Inject]
    private readonly LoginViewModel _loginViewModel;

    public LoginController(ApiController apiController)
    {
        _apiController = apiController;
    }

    public void Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
    {
        try
        {
            string userJson = _apiController.PostLogin(loginViewModel.Username);

            _loginViewModel.ErrorMessage = "bla bla trololo";
            Debug.Log(userJson);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}

public class GameInstaller : MonoInstaller
{
    [Inject]
    Settings _settings = null;

    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        InstallViewModels();
        InstallServices();
        InstallSignals();
        InstallControllers();
    }

    private void InstallViewModels()
    {
        Container.Bind<LoginViewModel>().AsSingle();
    }

    private void InstallControllers()
    {
        Container.Bind<LoginController>().AsSingle().NonLazy();
        Container.Bind<ApiController>().AsSingle().NonLazy();
    }

    private void InstallServices()
    {
    }

    private void InstallSignals()
    {
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Settings
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from here: https://unitylist.com/p/ja3/Unity-MVVM

> A ViewModel (or VM) is what holds the data that will be presented on a view. It contains all the properties that can be bound to view elements. All ViewModels inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged which alerts the system when data changes and a UI element needs to be updated.

Since the ViewModel is in it's essence a simple object and not a service, I argue that it does not need go be injected anywhere.

What you could do, is inject a `Factory` and get your ViewModel from it.

In your code you are trying to inject the controller into your ViewModel and not the other way round.